# Formatting dataframe in appending

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates, append

I want to append 2 dataframes:

```
data1:
     a
1    a
2    b
3    c
4    d
5    e

data2:
     b
1    f   
2    g
3    h
4    i
5    j

output:

1    a
2    b
3    c
4    d
5    e
6    f   
7    g
8    h
9    i
10   j
```

currently i am using:

```
all_data= data1.append(data2, ignore_index=True)
```

this gives me result as:

```
     a    b
1    a
2    b
3    c
4    d
5    e
6        f   
7        g
8        h
9        i
10       j
```

i.e. in different columns. 
How can i get them in the same column?

Also tried converting the dataframes into list and then tring to append it. But it gave me the error:

```
TypeError: append() takes no keyword arguments
```

Also, is there any other function to remove duplicates from the datarame of strings? The drop_duplicates() function does not work in my case. The data still has duplicates.

Comment: What would the column name for output be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change one column name, so `append` can detect hat you want to do:

```
data2.columns = ["a"]
```

or

```
data1.columns = ["b"]
```

And then, after using `data2.columns = ["a"]`:

```
all_data = data1.append(data2, ignore_index=True)
all_data
   a
0  a
1  b
2  c
3  d
4  e
5  f
6  g
7  h
8  i
9  j
```

And here you have your column named after the column's name of data1, which you can rename if you want:

```
all_data.columns = ["Foo"]
```

Comment: could you please help me out in removing the duplicates from the appended data? The drop_duplicate() function does not seem to work.

Comment: @eclairs : ask a separate question, also I don't see what is duplicated

Answer (score 1):

`merge` or `concat` work on keys. In this case, there are no common columns. However, why not use `numpy append` and create the dataframe?

```
In [68]: pd.DataFrame(pd.np.append(data1.values, data2.values), columns=['A'])
Out[68]:
   A
0  a
1  b
2  c
3  d
4  e
5  f
6  g
7  h
8  i
9  j
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df1.columns = ['b']

Out[78]:
b
0   a
1   b
2   c
3   d
4   e

pd.concat([df1 , df2] , ignore_index=True)


Out[80]:
b
0   a
1   b
2   c
3   d
4   e
5   f
6   g
7   h
8   i
9   j
```